# Phusion Passenger 3.2 experimental

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I need run 2 versions of ruby with my apache and I can try new passenger experimental. But I don't know how install it, because when I try this:

```
sudo ./bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Installations is ok, but file mod_passenger.so don't exist.

Comment: The 'Passenger experimental' link appears to be broken

Comment: They deleted experimental branch from repository. New version of passenger will be support multiple ruby versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passenger 3.x supports a single ruby interpreter only.

> 5.2. PassengerRuby
>
> This option allows one to specify the Ruby interpreter to use.
>
> This option may only occur once, in the global server configuration. The default is ruby.

[Passenger 4.x supports multiple rubies natively](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby): (excert from the docs)

**6.2. PassengerRuby**

This option allows one to specify the Ruby interpreter to use.

Since version 4.0.0, this option may occur in the following places:

- In the global server configuration.
- In a virtual host configuration block.
- In a  or  block.
- In .htaccess, if AllowOverride Options is on.

If you want to use a different Ruby interpreter for two different applications then you should define different PassengerRuby directives in different virtual host blocks.

In versions prior to 4.0.0, only a single Ruby version is supported for the entire Apache instance, so PassengerRuby may only occur in the global server configuration.

The default value is ruby, meaning that the Ruby interpreter will be looked up according to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use passenger gem, start your app in standalone mode with passenger and use reverse proxy into your apache conf(httpd).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName locahost
DocumentRoot /home/test/www/second_app/public
RailsEnv development
PassengerEnabled off
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000
</VirtualHost>
```